# Qué tipo de datos debería usar en mysql en un campo que puede admitir enteros o decimales?

Tags: base-de-datos

Necesito guardar registros de lecturas de datos en un tabla, las lecturas provienen de diferentes sensores, algunos devuelven un numero entero (Ej. 998), otros un número con un lugar decimal después del punto (Ej 26.3), mi pregunta es, teniendo en cuenta que mas adelante pueda usar eficientemente este campo (al que llamaré "lectura") para obtener reportes, cómo debería definirlo? Cómo float?

Así seria mi tabla

```
id_sensor | lectura| fecha
sensor 1  | 998    | 31/02/2020
sensor 2  | 23.1   | 31/02/2020 
sensor 1  | 443    | 01/03/2020
sensor 2  | 26.1   | 01/03/2020
```

Comment: Elige el tipo decimal

Comment: Cual es el tipo nativo al que haces referencia? Float u otro?

Comment: Eso dependerá que motor de bases de datos uses, pero al menos en MySQL y MariaDB se llama DECIMAL

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto compañero debes de definirlo como float ya que guardara campos decimales y debe de saber cuántos decimales devuelve para poner esa cantidad y no tenga problema en el guardado.